# How to remove empty space on down of my layout?

Tags: android, layout

i have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJNzQ.png) layout

I have a scroolview in the root , an edittext and a linear layout in the root of each section of the three imagebutton

It looks like this on some devices, I want it to look like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzvML.png) on everyone

How to do this? Here is my **XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrool"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#bbbbbb"
    android:fillViewport="false">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#bbbbbb"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Количество дней"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/winter"
                    android:layout_width="192dp"
                    android:layout_height="183dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:onClick="Winter"

                    android:paddingTop="32sp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/winter"
                    android:text="Зима"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/Middle"
                    android:layout_width="192dp"
                    android:layout_height="183dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:onClick="Middle"
                    android:paddingTop="32sp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/listok"
                    android:text="Весна/Осень"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/Summer"
                    android:layout_width="192dp"
                    android:layout_height="183dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:onClick="Summer"
                    android:paddingTop="32sp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/summer"
                    android:text="Лето"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/man"
                    android:layout_width="192dp"
                    android:layout_height="183dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:onClick="Man"
                    android:paddingTop="32sp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/man"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/child"
                    android:layout_width="192dp"
                    android:layout_height="183dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:onClick="Child"
                    android:paddingTop="32sp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/child"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/woman"
                    android:layout_width="192dp"
                    android:layout_height="183dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:onClick="Woman"
                    android:paddingTop="32sp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/woman"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/turizm"
                    android:layout_width="192dp"
                    android:layout_height="183dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:onClick="turizm"
                    android:paddingTop="32sp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/turizm"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/komandirovka"
                    android:layout_width="192dp"
                    android:layout_height="183dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:onClick="komandirovka"
                    android:paddingTop="32sp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/komandirovka"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/plyazh"
                    android:layout_width="192dp"
                    android:layout_height="183dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:onClick="plyazh"
                    android:paddingTop="32sp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"

                    android:src="@drawable/plyazh"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Thank you for any help. I am racking brains now.

---

Here i add some text to let stackoverflow post my question

*Table in the department of computer support:
Theory is when you know everything, but nothing works.
Practice is when everything works, but no one knows why.
AT THIS PLACE we combine theory and practice - nothing works and no one knows why!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code according to my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#bbbbbb"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Количество дней"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/winter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="Winter"
            android:paddingTop="32sp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_app"
            android:text="Зима"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Middle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="Middle"
            android:paddingTop="32sp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_app"
            android:text="Весна/Осень"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Summer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="Summer"
            android:paddingTop="32sp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_app"
            android:text="Лето"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/man"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="Man"
            android:paddingTop="32sp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_app"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/child"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="Child"
            android:paddingTop="32sp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_app"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/woman"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="Woman"
            android:paddingTop="32sp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_app"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/turizm"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="turizm"
            android:paddingTop="32sp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_app"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/komandirovka"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="komandirovka"
            android:paddingTop="32sp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_app"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/plyazh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="plyazh"
            android:paddingTop="32sp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_app"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it will help

This code is tested my myself and it is working

Thankew! Happy coding!

Comment: but i have the same problem, i have empty space now too

Comment: Then change your  LinearLayout height also to wrap_content

Comment: Is you want to make your dashboard items fit on screen?

Comment: Ohk! now i got it. Let me edit my answer now I'm uploading new code for you

Comment: no problem but we have to remove scroll view is it is ok for you?

Comment: no problem, i added scroolview because i was afraid that my layout will not fit on everyone screen

Comment: Please check and inform me it is working or not and please change drawable images by yourself

Comment: Thank you! It works! But my first group is bigger than others. How to fix it? https://imgur.com/a/8msSLFO

Comment: If you copy the code same as mine Then, check the image sizes all image size must be same

Comment: Thank you! Greetings from Russia!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **dp** sizes, it depends to size of phone and you won't have what you want. Use **weight** to coordinate layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Make the height of both `ScrollView` and the direct inner `LinearLayout` as wrap_content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrool"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#bbbbbb"
    android:fillViewport="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#bbbbbb"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: but i have the same problem, i have empty space now too

Comment: @rfheher, if you want to get the `ImageButton`s stretch out to fill the entire screen, then you can't use fixed height of your `ImageButton`'s

Comment: but how to make my android:layout_height ?